# How to set different time limits for different model called from inside a main model?

Tags: cplex, opl

I am calling multiple MIP mod files from main as { call model1.mod;
call model2.mod}. I want to set the time limit to those called mod files. My problem can be structured as:

***mod file with main***

1 variable definitions, initialization
2 execute {cplex.tilim=60;}  //i want to run the model for 60 seconds

4 {max obj function }, st{ constraints }

6 main{

8 call model1;  //call simply represents calling for model
9 call model2;

11 }

I set the time limit inside the model1 and model2 files, but that does not work. Can someone help me to set the time limit?

Comment: I understand this for the main model. But how do we set the time limit for models or sub models that are called from main?

Answer (score 2):

In your main just before the cplex call you may set the time limit like this:

```
  cplex.tilim=10; // 10 s
  cplex.solve();
```

A complete example at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=72359501-c169-4215-9dc0-1c87e653b584&ps=25

Comment: In the cutstock example, how should I set the time limit for solving the integer master model if I want to set the time limit only to solve the integer master model?